# Using response from Previous Task Durable Task Framework

Tags: azure, durable-task-framework

I'm writing a project which is event based using Durable Task Framework.

Below One is the Orchestrator.

```
public class WorkflowOrchestrator : TaskOrchestration<long, string>
     {
         TaskCompletionSource<string> resumeHandle;
         public override async Task<long> RunTask(OrchestrationContext context, string instanceId)
         {
             string eventTriggered = await WaitForSignal();
             Console.WriteLine($"Event Triggered {eventTriggered}");
             do
             {
                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventTriggered))
                 {
                     var workflow = await context.ScheduleTask<List<WorkflowActivityMap>>(typeof(WorkflowActivityMapperFetcher), 1);
                     var taskToBeExecuted = await context.ScheduleTask<TakExecuterRequest>(typeof(WorkflowSetupInitilzerTask), new WorkflowSetupInitilzerParameter()
                     {
                         InstanceId = instanceId,
                         workflow = workflow,
                         StepIndex = eventTriggered
                     });
                     if (taskToBeExecuted != null)
                     {
                         var task = await context.ScheduleTask<TaskActivityReponse>(taskToBeExecuted.TaskType, taskToBeExecuted.Parameters);
                         Console.WriteLine($"Response is {task?.Response}"); 
                     } 
                 }
                 eventTriggered = "";
             } while (eventTriggered != "999");
             return 0;
         }
    
         async Task<string> WaitForSignal()
         {
             this.resumeHandle = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
             string data = await this.resumeHandle.Task;
             this.resumeHandle = null;
             return data;
         }
    
         public override void OnEvent(OrchestrationContext context, string name, string input)
         {
             this.resumeHandle?.SetResult(input);
         }
```

My requirement is First It should fetch workflow task details from database ,which will be done by WorkflowActivityMapperFetcher.

Second it will get the type of task to be executed and parameters for the task from the list of tasks

After that I'll execute the task. and get the response

My WorkflowSetupInitilzerTask class is as below

```
public sealed class WorkflowSetupInitilzerTask : TaskActivity<WorkflowSetupInitilzerParameter, TakExecuterRequest>
 {
     protected override TakExecuterRequest Execute(TaskContext context, WorkflowSetupInitilzerParameter input)
     {
         var result = new TakExecuterRequest(typeof(EmptyActivity), new ApiActivityParam());
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.StepIndex) && int.TryParse(input.StepIndex, out int index))
         {
             var dbContext = new WorkflowDbContext();
             var activityToExecute = input.workflow.First(x => x.StepIndex == index);
             var activity = dbContext.Activities.First(x => x.Id == activityToExecute.ActivityId);

             switch (activity.ActivityName)
             {
                 case ApiCallActivity.Identifier:
                     result = new TakExecuterRequest(typeof(ApiCallActivity), new ApiActivityParam()
                     {
                         Property = activityToExecute.Parameters,
                         InstanceId = input.InstanceId,
                         StepCount = activityToExecute.StepIndex
                     });
                     break;
                 case EmailActivity.Identifier:
                     result = new TakExecuterRequest(typeof(EmailActivity), new EmailActivityParam()
                     {
                         InstanceId = input.InstanceId,
                         Property = activityToExecute.Parameters,
                         StepCount = activityToExecute.StepIndex
                     });
                     break;
                 default:
                     throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Activity");
             }
             return result; 
         }
         return null;
     }
 }
```

to trigger the event I use another console application, which code will be like below

```
using DurableTask.Core;
using DurableTask.SqlServer;

Console.WriteLine("Workflow Tester!");
var instanceID = "633e6107e5cc4b6e8e7776945576ade5"; // this is copied from console log of Orchestrator project
string storageConnectionString = "database-settings";

var settings = new SqlOrchestrationServiceSettings(storageConnectionString, taskHubName)
{
    WorkItemLockTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2500),
};


var orchestrationServiceAndClient = new SqlOrchestrationService(settings);
var taskHubClient = new TaskHubClient(orchestrationServiceAndClient);

var instance = new OrchestrationInstance { InstanceId = instanceID };
var isExit = false;
while (!isExit)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Index");
    var index = Console.ReadLine();
    taskHubClient.RaiseEventAsync(instance, "WorkflowUpdated", index).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue?");
    var response = Console.ReadLine();
    isExit = response == "n";
}
```

I've 2 issues,

1. When I give the the index on the testing console app, it works only once, then no update on the Orchestrator side
2. How can I access response from previously executed task in current execution.